# Installing Chrome/Chromium on Centos7- kiosk mode

Tags: chrome, kiosk

I am new on Centos7 and have some issues. I want to install chrome/chromium on centos7, make user autologin and open to specific webpage in kiosk mode. I did the same on Debian easily but my Intel Nuc doesnt support Debian and I am quite out of options. If anyone could help it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use something like the following:

1. Enable selinux enforcing
   Edit /etc/selinux/config to enforcing mode
2. Install xguest and desktop(gui)

   `yum -y groupinstall basic-desktop desktop-platform x11 fonts`
   `yum -y install xguest chromium xorg-x11-xinit-session`
3. Create .xsession in xguest homedir
4. Exec chromium in kiosk mode in .xsession

   `cat << EOF > ~xguest/.xsession`
   `#!/bin/sh`
   `exec chromium --kiosk`
   `EOF`
   `chmod +x ~xguest/.xsession`
5. Autologin with xguest
   Edit the /etc/gdm/custom.conf file and make sure that the [daemon] section in the file specifies the following:

   `[daemon]`
   `AutomaticLoginEnable=True`
   `AutomaticLogin=xguest`
6. Set the system to boot into graphical mode

   `systemctl set-default graphical.target`
7. Some hardening
   `yum remove nautilus gnome-panel`

This is mostly from memory, test and modify as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo yum install google-chrome
```

Then open chrome settings and set your certain page to be opened on entry - you can also set chrome to open every time you boot up using the command:

```
mate-session-properties
```

For running mate and:

```
gnome-session-properties
```

For those running Gnome, click ADD and then find the startup for chrome and make it startup each time you login.